# How to check if last character of a string is a digit/number by the fastest way in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, ends-with

How to check if last character of a string is a digit/number in plain JavaScript?

```js
function endsWithNumber(str){
  return str.endsWith(); // HOW TO CHECK IF STRING ENDS WITH DIGIT/NUMBER ???
}

var str_1 = 'Pocahontas';
var str_2 = 'R2D2';

if (endsWithNumber(str_1)) {
  console.log(str_1 + 'ends with a number');
} else {
  console.log(str_1 + 'does NOT end with a number');
}

if (endsWithNumber(str_2)) {
  console.log(str_2 + 'ends with a number');
} else {
  console.log(str_2 + 'does NOT end with a number');
}
```

Also I would like to know what would be the most fastest way? I guess it may sound ridiculous :D but in my usecase I will need this method very often so I think it could make a difference.

Comment: @str, my bad totally forgot about "NaN". So then, `var str = "R2D2"; -> isNaN(str[str.length - 1]) === false && typeof +str[str.lenght - 1] === "number;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**Conditional (ternary) operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) with [**`isNaN()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and [**String.prototype.slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
function endsWithNumber(str){
  str = str.trim();
  if (!str) return 'Invalid input'; //return if input is empty
  return isNaN(str.slice(-1)) ? 'does NOT end with a number' : 'ends with a number';
}

console.log(endsWithNumber('Pocahontas'));
console.log(endsWithNumber('R2D2'));
console.log(endsWithNumber(''));
```

Comment: This returns "ends with a number" if the string is empty or ends with a space.

Comment: @GuillaumeF., updated the answer to handle the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
function endsWithNumber( str: string ): boolean {

    return str && str.length > 0 && str.charAt( str.length - 1 ).match( /[0-9A-Za-z]/ );
}
```

Comment: This will not actually return a boolean as .match() returns either null or an array.

Use something like `str.charAt( str.length - 1 ).match( /[0-9]/ ) != null`  instead, or better yet use RegExp.prototype.test().